# Calling a method from a class method in ApplicationRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a strange issue
I have the implementation below:
In a controller
Event.search(search_params)

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  def self.search(params)
    find_events(params)
  end
  private

  def find_events(params)
    events = Event.upcoming
    events = events.where("name like ?", "%#{params['name']}%")
    events
  end 
end
```

When executed I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `find_events' for #<Class:0x007fadcd00a690>)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the class method with

```
def self.find_events
```

You cannot call an instance method from a class method without an instance object attached to that method.

Comment: great. Thanks. I ended up creating a search model.
Much cleaner